# How do I get the difference in seconds and milliseconds between 3 dates?

Tags: java, time

I have three **different** Dates, in this format:

```
long firstDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
long secondDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
long thirdDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

The *firstDate* is the starting point.

I want the seconds + milliseconds that have passed between the starting point and to the others.

Example:

> firstDate = 0.000

> secondDate= 1.234
>
> thirdDate = 2.345

Comment: Is this a question about the calculation of the values or the formatting (with the dot) of the output? What have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

First, understand that `System.currentTimeMillis` was supplanted years ago by `java.time.Instant`.

```
Instant x = Instant.now() ;
```

Calculate elapsed time with `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.between ( x , y ) ;
```

Tip: To represent each span of time, add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to your project for its `Interval` class.

Comment: For output like `1.234` one may use `String.format("%d.%03d", d.toSeconds(), d.toMillisPart())`.

Answer (score 1):

```
final long totalDiffInMillis = thirdDate - firstDate;
final long diffSeconds = totalDiffInMillis / 1000;
final long diffMillis = totalDiffInMillis % 1000;

System.out.printf("Diff between thirdDate and firstDate: %d seconds, %d milliseconds", 
                   diffSeconds,
                   diffMillis);
```

Comment: It is just one of several ways to strip decimals from a decimal number. Will update with printf.

Comment: Was a bit unsure if there would be rounding issues, but after testing it out it seems it would just throw away the decimals. Would be simpler then.

Answer (score 1):

For your case, you can use [Stopwatch](https://guava.dev/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) from Google Guava.

Google Guava Stopwatch – Creation

Google Guava offers a stopwatch class to measure time. It has two methods to create a stopwatch – one that creates a stopwatch instance in running state and the other just creates a stopwatch object without starting it.

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
```

The above returns a stopwatch while in a running state.

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.create();
```

Calling the create() method creates a stopwatch that is not started yet.
Google Guava Stopwatch – Measuring elapsed time

We call the elapsed time passing the time unit to get the time elapsed.

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
Thread.sleep(100);
System.out.println(stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

The above would print a number little over 100. This applies to all the measurements shown here, as none of them can provide an accurate measurement. Even Thread.sleep’s accuracy depends on thread schedulers and a lot of other factors.

However, the preferred method to get the elapsed time is to use the elapsed() method which returns a Duration object. The Duration object belongs to java.time package.

```
Duration elapsed = stopwatch.elapsed();
System.out.println(elapsed.toMillis());
```

Once we have a Duration instance, we can do a lot of things by using the methods on it (You can explore the methods on a Duration class).
Starting, Stopping and Resetting a Google Guava Stopwatch

If the stopwatch was created by calling the create() method or is in a stopped state, we can start it by calling the start() method. To stop a stopwatch, call the stop() method.

Until you start a stopwatch, it will not measure the time elapsed.

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createUnstarted();
Thread.sleep(100);
stopwatch.start();
Thread.sleep(100);
System.out.println(stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

In the above code, the stopwatch will not consider the first sleep call’s execution time as the stopwatch was started only after it (at line 3). Hence, the output will only include the last sleep’s execution time.

```
System.out.println(stopwatch.isRunning());//true
stopwatch.stop();
System.out.println(stopwatch.isRunning());//false
```

The stopwatch’s isRunning method returns true if the stopwatch is still running. We can call the elapsed() method even if the stopwatch is stopped (calling elapsed over and over will keep returning the same value once the stopwatch is stopped).

Now if we start the stopwatch, it will start counting, adding to the already elapsed time. If we want to start over, call the reset() method which will reset the stopwatch’s elapsed time count to 0 and stops the stopwatch.

```
stopwatch.reset();
stopwatch.start();
Thread.sleep(100);
System.out.println(stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

The methods start() and stop() must be called only once at a time. If we call back to back (consecutive) start() or stop() it throws an IllegalStateException. In other words, we cannot start a stopwatch that is already running and vice versa for stopping.

Examples copied from this page [click](https://javadevcentral.com/measuring-elapsed-time-using-a-stopwatch).